# How to select a single contact from contacts in flutter

Tags: flutter, fetch, contacts

I have been stuck on this problem. How to select and fetch details from a contact in flutter? Please ​help.

Answer (score 3):

Add this dependenncy

**This is the current version by this time**

> contact_picker: ^0.0.2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contact_picker/contact_picker.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(new MyApp());
 } 

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final ContactPicker _contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
  Contact _contact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
   home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
       title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
     ),
      body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
         children: <Widget>[
          new MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: new Text("CLICK ME"),
            onPressed: () async {
              Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
              setState(() {
                _contact = contact;
              });
            },
          ),
          new Text(
            _contact == null ? 'No contact selected.' : _contact.toString(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with contacts_service: ^0.2.5 , u can search this by adding query , but i didnt found by phone or by email if u have any idea.

https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service#-readme-tab-

```
Iterable<Contact> johns = await ContactsService.getContacts(query : "john");
```

Comment: I want to open the phonebook and select contact. not search brother. If you can help.

Comment: ok sorry i didnt get it, try contact picker    https://pub.dev/packages/contact_picker

Answer (score 0):

The [fluttercontactpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttercontactpicker) package is the best package for opening native phonebook. It is *null safe* and works out the contact permissions on it's own.
You can `pickPhoneContact` or `pickEmailContact` as be your requirement.

```
final PhoneContact contact =
await FlutterContactPicker.pickPhoneContact();
```

And if you want the entire contact to be fetched then you can user the `pickFullContact()` method.

```
final FullContact contact =
await FlutterContactPicker.pickFullContact();
```

*Note* : This method only works in Android and not iOS. So you might have to add a platform check if you're using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contact_picker` package managing contacts.

Add the following the your `pubscpec.yaml`

```
contact_picker: ^0.0.2
```

You can use a method like the to open a contact picker and return a phone number:

```
Future<String> pickMobileNumber() async {
  final contact = await ContactsService.openDeviceContactPicker();
  if (contact == null) {
    return null;
  }
  // Picks the first num with label mobile
  final mobilePhone = contact.phones.firstWhere(
    (phone) => phone.label?.toLowerCase() == 'mobile',
    orElse: () => null,
  );
  if (mobilePhone == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return mobilePhone.value;
}
```